# Nginx rewrite filename as a directory

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want to rewrite a file name `membership-list.html` as a directory on the root domain as `membership-list/`. I had this in my config file:

```
location = ^/membership-list.html {
    rewrite ^/membership-list.html ^/membership-list/ redirect;
}
```

I searched around and couldn't find any information regarding redirecting from a file to a directory name.

Comment: Please share the outcome, errors, and what did you try? Did yo enable rewrite_log? What did it say?

Comment: `location = ^/membership-list.html` will match impossible url `^/membership-list.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it outside the location block and inside the server block.

```
rewrite ^/membership-list.html /membership/;
```

Then create the location with whatever you need:

```
location /membership/ { }
```

https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/regular-expression-caret-or-circumflex-in-character-class/

Comment: @ xtine.k: Don't you think you could mark this as "answered"?